# Typescript: how to fix missing export in embedded definition?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm using a package from npm, let's say `foo`. This package has an embedded definiton file `node_modules/foo/index.ts.d`. However, there is an export missing from this file. Therefore, typescript won't let me compile, giving me the error: `Module '.../foo' has no exported member 'Bar'.`

How to I augment, replace or fix the definiton for the `foo` package?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [module augmentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to add the missing export.
Simply place the following above your `import` statement:

```js
declare module 'foo' {
    export let Bar: {
       example_name: string, // etc
    };
}
```

```js
import {Bar} from 'foo';
```